# getting fields with $in in mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, limit

I have a collection and the example datas are like this,

{
L:"images",
K:"asdd"
}
{
L:"images",
K:"asdd"
}
{
L:"images",
K:"asdd"
}
{
L:"images",
K:"asdd"
}
{
L:"images",
K:"asdd"
}
{
L:"images",
K:"asdd"
}
{
L:"images",
K:"asdd"
}
{
L:"images",
K:"asdd"
}
{
L:"images",
K:"asdd"
}
{
L:"images",
K:"asdd"
}
{
L:"images",
K:"asdd"
}
{
L:"images",
K:"asdd"
}
{
L:"images",
K:"asdd"
}

and other fields are,{L:"cars",K:"asdff"},{L:"table",K:"asgeg"} those fields have at least 20 documents too, what I want as a result is like this

{
L:"images",
K:"asdd"
}
{
L:"images",
K:"asdd"
}

{
L:"cars",
K:"asdd"
}
{
L:"cars",
K:"asdd"
}

{
L:"table",
K:"asdd"
}
{
L:"table",
K:"asdd"
}

I want to get the documents according to their L field, but I want to limit every field's result to two and I have no idea how to manage this, thank you for any reply :)

Comment: I tried db.user.find("L"=>array('$in'=>array("cars","table","images")))->limit(30)

Comment: no, there are fields named "L" and they have different values, but I only need 2 table, 2 images and 2 cars out of the collection

Comment: OK, so if that's an array in a single document (as opposed to collection of documents), wouldn't it be more efficient and easier to query to make them each a document in a collection rather than an array of entries? When you say "document" do you mean "object" entry in the array?

Comment: It is not array of entities, they are documents, that have a field named "L", I need only the query

Comment: What mongo version are you on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your schema, I don't think there is a way, in a single query, to do what you want.  I would recommend a PHP script with a simple [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop, or similar, to extract the values you want since you tagged this one as PHP.

Of course, you can just do it with 3 separate queries, one for each L value, with a limit of 2.  I assume that we are really talking about a lot of distinct values and not just the three listed.

I'm not a PHP guy, so I can't help you out there, but you can use the JavaScript capabilities of the shell similarly like this (I loaded your sample data into a collection called foo and it had an _id field added automatically):

```
db.foo.distinct("L").forEach(function(key) {
    db.foo.find({"L" : key}, {_id : 0}).limit(2).forEach(
        function (value) {
            printjson(value);
        }
    )
})
```

I used distinct to generate the three values but you could easily just pass it in as an array  on the first line like so:

```
['images', 'cars', 'table'].forEach(function(key) {
```

Either way, the function gave me the following output:

```
{ "L" : "images", "K" : "asdd" }
{ "L" : "images", "K" : "asdd" }
{ "L" : "cars", "K" : "asdd" }
{ "L" : "cars", "K" : "asdd" }
{ "L" : "table", "K" : "asdd" }
{ "L" : "table", "K" : "asdd" }
```